# Using php variables within mysql query ? stuck

Tags: php, mysql, session

```
//check if the username which the user entered exists in the database
$usr = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE username = '".$usr."'";
$query = mysqli_query($sql,$conn);

//if u found any row with that condition...
if ($query->num_rows != 0)
{
    //some code here.....
}
```

this is my code and it returns $query and $query->num_rows as NULL everytime.
And I'm sure I have 'mehdijjz' (the $usr) in my table.
I think the problem lies in the syntax of the $sql code.
i'm so stuck... :( what do you think ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Maybe `$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);` would help?

Comment: I don't see a syntax error in the SQL, but please do look into using prepared statements rather than concatenating values into the SQL string like that. The way you are doing it should work, but is not safe for your database.

Comment: Also, this is not included in the code in your question, so you may already be doing it, but before you try to execute any queries, be sure to verify that you have a functioning database connection.

Comment: while making sure the session was indeed started.

Answer (score 1):

See, this is why I hate the procedural *mysqli* API. If you're used to the *mysql* API, you get the arguments the wrong way around.

In any case, you should...

1. Use prepared statements for injecting query values
2. Enable proper error reporting in your `php.ini` config file for development

   ```
   error_reporting = E_ALL
   display_errors = On
   ```

You can also simplify the logic around checking for existing records. For example

```
// make mysqli throw exceptions
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM `login` WHERE `username` = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['username']);
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    //some code here.....
}
```

Comment: thanks your answer helped me alot !